# parse url string in spark df with PySpark

Tags: python, string, apache-spark, parsing, pyspark

I need to parse url strings from column `refererurl` in spark df. The data looks like this:

```
refererurl
https://www.delish.com/cooking/recipes/t678
https://www.delish.com/food/recipes/a463/
https://www.delish.com/cooking/recipes/g877
```

I am only interested in what comes after `delish.com`. Desired output is:

```
content
cooking
food
cooking
```

I have tried:

```
data.withColumn("content", fn.regexp_extract('refererurl', 'param1=(\d)', 2))
```

Returns all null values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [parse_url](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#parse_url) to the get the path of the url and then get the first level of the path with [regexp_extract](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#regexp_extract):

```python
df.withColumn("content", fn.expr("regexp_extract(parse_url(refererurl, 'PATH'),'/(.*?)/')")) \
    .show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------------------------+-------+
|refererurl                                 |content|
+-------------------------------------------+-------+
|https://www.delish.com/cooking/recipes/t678|cooking|
|https://www.delish.com/food/recipes/a463/  |food   |
|https://www.delish.com/cooking/recipes/g877|cooking|
+-------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: `F.expr(r"split(parse_url(refererurl, 'PATH'), '/')")[1]` - very similar, but `split` instead of `regexp_extract`

Answer (score 1):

**One more way of solving the problem using Split and element_at function in case we know the position of the string always remains same.**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,"https://www.delish.com/cooking/recipes/t678"), (2,"https://www.delish.com/food/recipes/a463/"),(3,"https://www.delish.com/cooking/recipes/g877")],[ "col1","col2"])
df.show(truncate=False)
df = df.withColumn("splited_col", F.split("col2", "/"))
df = df.withColumn("content", F.element_at(F.col('splited_col'), 4).alias('content'))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

**Input**

```
+----+-------------------------------------------+
|col1|col2                                       |
+----+-------------------------------------------+
|1   |https://www.delish.com/cooking/recipes/t678|
|2   |https://www.delish.com/food/recipes/a463/  |
|3   |https://www.delish.com/cooking/recipes/g877|
+----+-------------------------------------------+
```

**Output**

```
 +----+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+-------+


|col1|col2                                       |splited_col                                       |content|
+----+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+-------+
|1   |https://www.delish.com/cooking/recipes/t678|[https:, , www.delish.com, cooking, recipes, t678]|cooking|
|2   |https://www.delish.com/food/recipes/a463/  |[https:, , www.delish.com, food, recipes, a463, ] |food   |
|3   |https://www.delish.com/cooking/recipes/g877|[https:, , www.delish.com, cooking, recipes, g877]|cooking|
+----+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+-------+
```